# Android - How to get current user coordinates/location on demand?

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation, gps

I have an Activity with a button, I just want the button to get current user location via gps/internet/etc and show a toast with those coordinates. That's all, just check the coords once, and show them. Only and every time I click the button, the coords should be updated and shown.

How can I do this? I'm having some trouble understanding LocationManager (if that's what I should be using)

I have these in manifest

```
"android.permission.INTERNET"
"android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"
"android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"
"android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"
```

The logcat only shows Couldn't get connection factory client on app startup. The app shows a mapview at first, and that is working ok, so I don't know if that error is my problem.

I did:

```
...
LocationManager mlocManager = 

(LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();
mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);
....
    public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener
    {    @Override public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)
{           
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
textView.setText("Latitud: "+loc.getLatitude()+" , Longitud"+loc.getLongitude());
}
...
}
```

But **it's not changing** textview2 value

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions. This is not a question.

Comment: Edited the title. Sorry*

Comment: The location is updated and the onLocationChanged method runs when the GPS chip gets a fix and the OS decides to deliver it, not when you press a button.

Comment: @NickT That's the answer, I can't, thanks.

Comment: Take a look at this great tutorial, it does what you need. You can download the sourcecode too. http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

Use a global variable in `onLocationChanged(Location l)` and `onClick()` off the button you se the value. The value will always be actualized.